# PDO: how do I fetch a single record by column name

Tags: php, mysql

I have one row of data, I'm trying to retrieve a single record by column name but nothing is returned.

What am I doing wrong? I'm new to MySQL.

My DB

```
       id        column1           column2        column3

row     1        apple             orange         grape
```

My PHP code

```
<?php
include("/secure/authdb.php");

$submitdata = "orange";

$SQL = $authdb -> prepare("SELECT `$submitdata` FROM `tablefruit` WHERE `id=1`");
$SQL -> execute();
$returnfruit = $SQL -> fetchColumn(0);

die($returnfruit);
```

Comment: Way too many problems in this code to cover here, but a big clue is the statement die($returnfruit);

Comment: your `WHERE` clause is incorrect with the ticks around the whole thing. It should just be the column that should be ticked or not at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think

```
 $SQL = $authdb -> prepare("SELECT `$submitdata` FROM `tablefruit` WHERE `id=1`");
```

Should be

```
 $SQL = $authdb -> prepare("SELECT `$submitdata` FROM `tablefruit` WHERE `id`=1");
```

i.e. last quote should not around id field, not the whole bit.

Thats apart from the other issues.  You need to understand what SQL is there for and how to execute a statement in something like phpmyadmin to check your syntax first.

Comment: I apologize I'm new to mysql

Comment: If you want the value of column1, then this should go where you have $submitdata.  The WHERE clause is how you select which row you want to fetch.